# Sort function not working: sort an object by value

Tags: javascript

```
  <p id="demo">
  depending on what you clicked I will appear or hide.
  </p>

 <script>

  var items = [
    { name: "Edward", value: 21 },
    { name: "Sharpe", value: 37 },
    { name: "And", value: 45 },
    { name: "The", value: -12 },
    { name: "Magnetic", value: 13 },
    { name: "Zeros", value: 37 }
  ];

  //sort the object by value

  items.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.value - b.value;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      items[i].name + items[i].value;
  }
</script>
```

The output is And45, but the result I want is to display the object by value. 
Any advice is appreciated!Thank you in advance

Comment: Has nothing to do with sort. Your output code just replaces the text on every iteration. Either you do string concatenation or you append new elements.

Comment: You need to concatenate all those names and values and assign to innerHTML just once. You are now overridign it in every iteration.

Comment: Your sort function works fine. You just need to set the `innerHTML` with the correct string (containing all object's names and values)

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the for-loop and just use a map and join to transform the items into a string representation if that's what you're asking:

```js
var items = [
    { name: "Edward", value: 21 },
    { name: "Sharpe", value: 37 },
    { name: "And", value: 45 },
    { name: "The", value: -12 },
    { name: "Magnetic", value: 13 },
    { name: "Zeros", value: 37 }
  ];

  //sort the object by value

  items.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.value - b.value;
  });

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = items.map(o => `${o.name}: ${o.value}`).join('<br>');
```

```html
<p id="demo">
  depending on what you clicked I will appear or hide.
</p>
```

There's nothing wrong with your sort, you're just re-assigning the html several times, ending with the last value in the sorted array.

Comment: the `\n` is useless since it is not a textarea.

Comment: @epascarello right, my mistake. edited with proper breaks